# Very slow Innodb insert: 65secs for 1K entries in empty table

Tags: mysql, insert, innodb, database-performance

I notice that my mysql inserts are very slow. To test and demonstrate, I used the following table:

```
+----------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Table    | Create Table                                  |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------+
| ik_b64_8 | CREATE TABLE `incr_tbl` (
  `cnt` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cnt`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii COLLATE=ascii_bin |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

and python code:

```
def profile_basic(cnt):
    db = database.Connection("localhost","testing_delme","root", "")
    t1 = time.time()
    for ii in range(cnt):
        db.execute("INSERT INTO testing_delme.incr_tbl VALUES (%s)", ii)
    print time.time() - t1
```

When I run this insert-only code on an empty table, it consumes 65 secs for 1K inserts. I have innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1 and I need that as the tables can't afford to loose any data. My question is that with this set, can the insert get so slow? Or am I missing something else as well?

Comment: Have you tried inserting them all using a single statement?

Comment: start transaction; insert into foo (c1) values (v1),(v2),(v3); commit;

Comment: I haven't tried transaction as in the actual table (above is for demonstration only) I can only insert 1 entry at a time. It will be behind a webserver and capture user registrations. Hence that will not help. However, if that provides any clue, I can try it on this table and let you know.

Comment: FYI: I tried transaction. For 1K entries, it reports 70ms.

Comment: You should be using transactions regardless - start transaction; insert into foo (c1) values (v1); commit; -- or rollback.

Answer (score 1):

"Can't afford to lose any data." It's just a matter of degree. Without flushing you might lose the last second of data. With flushing, you might lose only the thing that was being written at the time. Do you really want to take a massive performance hit over that?

Also, if your disk breaks, you'll lose all data since your last backup anyway, which is inevitable in the long run and concerns much more data, so I'd be more worried about making frequent backups.

Disable the flushing. I reckon that'll easily take tens, if not hundreds of milliseconds per insert, because of all the disk activity. Having a few indexes on the table will make it even worse.

If, despite all this, you absolutely must flush on every write, you would also see big performance improvements if you put your database on an SSD.

Comment: The table that I am concerned about stores order information. As you say, worst case I loose 1 insert. My question is: does it take really 65ms per insert or are there other factors (apart from innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit) that I am missing out?

Comment: Well, just try turning off innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit and see how much of a difference it makes.

Comment: Yes, I had tried that. innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2 -> 140ms/1K insert. Setting it to 0 takes 109ms. I have also set innodb_file_per_table, which brings down the above values marginally down to 123ms and 109ms.

Answer (score 0):

I think you hit a limit in number of transactions per second. Each of your inserts is treated as a separate transaction, you must be in autocommit mode.

(1) Insert many rows in a single SQL statement, and you're ok:

```
insert into incr_tbl values (1),(2),(3)....
```

Python equivalent is something like this:

```
db.execute("insert into incr_tbl values %s" % ",".join(["(%s)" % i for i in range(xx)]))
```

(2) Alternatively you can start transaction explicitly:

```
db = ...(autocommit=False)
db.begin_transaction()
for i in xx: db.execute(... insert i ...)
db.commit()
```

If you have a decent server, you tx rate should be much much higher than 15 a second, so check your machine and mysql settings. Even if you commit to disk and wait every time (sqlite) you should be 100 tx/s on commodity hard drive. I have only seen rate this low when database was located usb flash. Another possible explanation is your python is very far away from the database and network latency kills performance, in this case (1) helps, (2) doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

With `db.execute()` you are inserting one-by-one and it will be very slow. Use the loop to build a list then do one bulk insert i.e. `db.executemany()`

```
def profile_basic(cnt):
    import mysql.connector, time
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect("localhost","testing_delme","root", "")
    db = cnx.cursor()
    list_ii = []
    t1 = time.time()
    for ii in range(cnt):
        list_ii.append(ii)
    # One bulk insert
    db.executemany("INSERT INTO testing_delme.incr_tbl VALUES (%s)", list_ii)
    # Don't forget to commit
    db.commit()
    print time.time() - t1
```

Comment: It has been quite long, but I think my case was to profile the insert, like an insert when a new user registers to the webapp. I think I am in the autocommit mode, default with torndb that I am using. Apart from removing autocommit and using transaction, are there any other mysql config that I should finetune for a better insert performance?

Comment: Even with autocommit=False then doing db.execute() and using db.commit() after the loop the code will add one-by-one then commit all. I had to add 600k inserts and it was taking me 10 seconds per 100 inserts (almost a whole day) Then I looked into it and changed it to db.executemany() and it did all 600k inserts under a minute.

Comment: Regarding your comment "insert when a new user registers" your performance in the title was 65s per 1k inserts so about 15 per second. If you have more users than that per second I'd cache new registrations then do a bulk insert with executemany(). For caching Google "memcached"

Comment: I can't use executemany() to insert multiples in a go. Let me put it in this way: I am profiling an insert, to get an idea of how long my instance takes when an user registers on my live website. It will be as and when an user registers, there are no many registrations to insert in a go. There's something definitely wrong with our mysql configuration or the way we are doing it.

Comment: I thought of caching in redis (which is live on my server) and doing bulk. However, caching/postponing insert for bulk entry just to gain on performance is not a good design. It adds unnecessary complexities to mask out issues lower. I use redis as read-only cache.